# Lighting Card onclick event.currentTarget doesn't work for guest users

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have an onclick handler setup on the lightning card below. This is working for authenicated users into the community but not for guest users. I have granted access to the apex class and related objects but for some reason all I can see if event.currentTarget doesn't get filled in only for the guest user.

So what can I do to make sure guest users are able to click these lightning cards?

```html
            <!-- Iterator over picklist to set the value attribute -->
            <lightning-card
              id={servcat.value.value}
              value={servcat.value}
              onclick={handleSearchServCategory}
              class="pressEnterCustomFunc"
              tabindex="0"
            >
```

```js
  handleSearchServCategory(event) {
    console.log("handle search service category...");
    try {
      console.log("event.currentTarget.value");
      console.log(event.currentTarget.value);

      this.srchParams.srchServCategory = event.currentTarget.value.value;
      this.selectedCategory.name = event.currentTarget.value.value;
      this.selectedCategory.img = event.currentTarget.value.img;
      console.log(this.selectedCategory.name);
      this.handleGetResourceList();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

**EDIT:**
I was able to setup a new sandbox from production where this is having this issue. In the new sandbox, without any changes other than publishing the community, the guest users are able to click the tiles. This is limited specifically to production.

**FINAL EDIT:**

Accepted answer is the best. Here is my updated code that was working to replace lightning card with how I had the styles

```html
            <article
              class="slds-card pressEnterCustomFunc"
              data-id={servcat.value.value}
              data-img={servcat.value.img}
              onclick={handleSearchServCategory}
              tabindex="0"
            >
```

One thing to not about passing data. You can have any number of single attributes (not JSON objects) on an article that you can then reference

```js
      this.selectedCategory.name = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
      this.selectedCategory.img = event.currentTarget.dataset.img;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a pure html card based off `slds`. This way you will always get any events because it's just plain HTML you are dealing with.

```
<article
  class="slds-card"
  data-id={servcat.value.value}
  onclick={handleSearchServCategory}
  class="pressEnterCustomFunc"
  tabindex="0" >
  <!-- header - which you can just remove if you don't want -->
  <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
    <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
      <div class="slds-media__figure">
        <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:account" alternative-text="Account" title="Account"></lightning-icon>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-media__body">
        <h2 class="slds-card__header-title">
          <a href="#" class="slds-card__header-link slds-truncate" title="Accounts">
            <span>Accounts</span>
          </a>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">{servcat.value}</div>
  <!-- you can also delete this -->
  <footer class="slds-card__footer">
      <a class="slds-card__footer-action" href="#">View All
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Accounts</span>
      </a>
    </footer>
</article>
```

The only difference you will have is that in your click handler, to extract the id, grab it from

```
event.currentTarget.dataset.id
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, its better to use plain HTML in this case instead of lightning-card elements because then I can set the property data-id which should be more easily retrievable? Is this not possible with Lightning components or just a way or avoiding glitches?